# Compare char in password String

Tags: java, string, char, compare

I have problem. I get this exercise but idk how i can resolve this last three solution in my code. I need print FAIL but i cant get because i only get OK OK i thats all.

I need to compare two passwords, one is String password and the other is String checkPassword. The program is to compare each letter or number separately, if it is the same it should print OK, so if it compares the password 123 to 123 it should write OK OK PASS, if 123 to 124 then OK OK FAIL, if 123 to 12 then OK OK FAIL, if 123 to 1234 is OK OK OK FAIL, and if 123 to 81234 it should throw FAIL.

```html
package NewPackage;

/*
    password = 123
checkPassword(123) -> OK OK PASS
checkPassword(124) -> OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(12) -> OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(1234) -> OK OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(81234) -> FAIL
*/

public class Tworzenie_tablicy_char {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String password = "123";
        String checkPassword = "12";

        char[] charPassword = new char[password.length()];
        char[] charCheckPassword = new char[checkPassword.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            charPassword[i] = password.charAt(i);
            //System.out.println(password.charAt(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkPassword.length(); i++) {
            charCheckPassword[i] = checkPassword.charAt(i);
            //System.out.println(checkPassword.charAt(i));
        }

        int minLength = Math.min(charPassword.length, charCheckPassword.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
            boolean correctly = charPassword[i] == charCheckPassword[i];

            if (correctly == true) {
                System.out.println("OK");
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Please explain more about the requirements of the task.  What constitutes `ok`, `fail`, and `pass`?  Also check out the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to convert to char string, you can use `charAt` to get characters. Take the min length and check if both chars at the same index are equal if a char is not equal then break out of the loop and make the fail flag to true and then show FAIL or PASS based on the fail flag.

```
public class Tworzenie_tablicy_char {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String password = "123";
        String checkPassword = "124";
        boolean fail = false;

        int minLength = Math.min(password.length(), checkPassword.length());
    
        for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
            if (password.charAt(i) == checkPassword.charAt(i))
                    System.out.println("OK");
            else{
                    fail = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        if(password.length() == checkPassword.length() && !fail)
            System.out.println("PASS");
        else
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        
    }
}
```

the output

```
java -cp /tmp/Jk7ZebI9iH Tworzenie_tablicy_char
OK
OK
FAIL
```

Comment: Thanks, now is much cleaner, but still have two sccenario doesnt do. First, when pass is 123 and check is 123 this should print OK OK PASS, and when pass is 123 and checkpass is 81234 should print only one FAIL. I think to give if pass.length is < checkpass.length then FAIL but this broke scenario 1234. :/

Comment: I assumed it needed FAIL every time, I have changed the code

Comment: FYI: `String#charAt` is legacy, and fails with most characters.

Answer (score 0):

to compare any methods, use

```
method.equals(method you want to compare);
```

if I did not understand this question, please let me know

Answer (score -1):

I get this solution but idk its correctly, i think i can get better and clean solution. :/

```html
package NewPackage;

/*
    password = 123
checkPassword(123) -> OK OK PASS
checkPassword(124) -> OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(12) -> OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(1234) -> OK OK OK FAIL
checkPassword(81234) -> FAIL
*/

public class Tworzenie_tablicy_char {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String password = "123";
        String checkPassword = "12";

        char[] charPassword = new char[password.length()];
        char[] charCheckPassword = new char[checkPassword.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            charPassword[i] = password.charAt(i);
            //System.out.println(password.charAt(i));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < checkPassword.length(); i++) {
            charCheckPassword[i] = checkPassword.charAt(i);
            //System.out.println(checkPassword.charAt(i));
        }

        int minLength = Math.min(charPassword.length, charCheckPassword.length);

        if (charPassword.length < charCheckPassword.length)
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
                boolean correctly = charPassword[i] == charCheckPassword[i];

                if (correctly == true) {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FAIL");
                }
            }
            if (charPassword.length != charCheckPassword.length) {
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what your intention is there. There's a lot of code there for seemingly little functionality. Why not ```java.lang.String.equals``` or at least ```java.lang.String.toCharArray``` ?